# iPhone - Easiest way to fill an NSMutableArray with randoms ints 0 to 3

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to fill an NSMutableArray with 100 random ints from 0 to 3. I'm still struggling with Objective-C...

Comment: don't forget that you can simply use c style arrays in objective-c. Probably using a int[] array is a few thousand times more performant then creating an object for every int and storing it in a nsarray .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

....

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() & 3]];
    }
```